Finding the smallest extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing a root of $x^4-2$
As $p(x)=x^4-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's criterion; $E=\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^4-2 \rangle$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $4$ containing a root of $x^4-2$,   $\alpha=x + \langle x^4-2\rangle$, so $E=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. If there were a smaller extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing a root $w$ of $p(x)$, then it'd have degree $2$ and there'd be a polynomial $d(x)$ of degree $2$ with $w$ as a root and as $p(x)=d(x)q(x)+r(x)$; $deg(r(x))<deg(d(x))$ and as $r(w)=0$, we have $r \equiv 0$, because if $deg(r(x))=1$, we'd have that $r(x)|p(x)$ and $p$ being irreducible would mean that $p$ and $r$ were associate. But similarly, as $d(x)|p(x)$, we'd have that $p$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ too. So, there is no smaller extension containing a root of $p(x)$ than $E=\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^4-2 \rangle$.
But could we conclude that $E=\mathbb{Q}[2^{\frac{1}{4}}]$ or $E=\mathbb{Q}[i2^{\frac{1}{4}}]$? We only know that $\alpha^4=2$ so we could have that either $\alpha^2=2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ or $\alpha^2=-2^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

You can't conclude whether the field is $\mathbb{Q} (2^{1/4})$ or $\mathbb{Q} (i2^{1/4})$. However these two fields are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} [x] /\langle x^4-2\rangle$ and it doesn't matter which we choose as far this exercise is concerned.

@Paramanand Singh, but we couldn't say that $\mathbb{Q}[2^{\frac{1}{4}}]$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Q}[i2^{\frac{1}{4}}]$ as the second one has an element whose square is $-\sqrt{2}$ and the first one hasn't got any such element, sure? So how could we still have that both are isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Q}[x]/ \langle x^4-2 \rangle$?

The isomorphism between these two fields preserves elements of $\mathbb{Q} $ and not necessarily elements of $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2})$. I mean there is no reason to expect this.

Remember the key theorem here: if $p(x) \in K[x] $ is irreducible of degree $n$ over $K$, with $K$ being an arbitrary field and $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ are roots of $p(x) $ then each $K(a_i) $ is isomorphic to $K[x] /\langle p(x) \rangle $. In other words there is no algebraic way to distinguish two roots of an irreducible polynomial.
